# Route parameter and object property are the same value, but are not equal to each other

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working on a project where I need to check if the value of a questions round_id is equal to the round id that i get from the parameters. However when I check them against each other, they are in fact the same value but do not "equal" each other.

Here is my code:

```
mounted() {

        //gets the params from the url
        this.routeParams = this.$route.params;

    },
    methods:{
        ...mapActions('question', ['newQuestion', 'fetchQuestions']),
        setOrderNumber() {

            //sets the order number for this question
            let $orderNumber = 1;
            console.log("The questions:");
            console.log(this.questions);

            for (let $i = 0; $i < this.questions.length; $i++)
            {
                console.log('this.questions[$i].round_id:');
                console.log(this.questions[$i].round_id);

                console.log('this.routeParams.round_id:');
                console.log(this.routeParams.round_id);

                console.log('this.questions[$i].round_id === this.routeParams.round_id:');
                console.log(this.questions[$i].round_id === this.routeParams.round_id);

                if(this.questions[$i].round_id === this.routeParams.round_id)
                {
                    console.log('$orderNumber before:');
                    console.log($orderNumber);

                    $orderNumber++;
                    console.log('$orderNumber after:');
                    console.log($orderNumber);

                }
            }
```

On the console, this is what I get: 
[image]

I notice that the 3 in question.round_id is blue and the route params.round_id is black. Is this potentially the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the numbers `3` you see in your console are of a different colour. The grey 3's are strings, just like the string you print before it. The blue `3`, just like the blue `false` you print are primitives. In this case, the blue `3` is a Number. You can verify this by logging `typeof this.questions[$i].rount_id` and `typeof this.routeParams.round_id`.

It is not surprising that the parameters from an url are strings, considering that the url itself is a string. Simply do a `parseInt(variable, 10);` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)) to parse it to a Number.

Comment: you are a gentlemen and a scholar. Thank you!